# Getting ElasticsearchStatusException and ElasticsearchResponseException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

What is ElasticsearchStatusException and ElasticsearchResponseException?

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/user_context/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [ignore_throttled]]

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://HOST_NAME:PORT], URI [/user_context/_refresh?ignore_throttled=false&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
```

This is what I am getting, when trying to run my JavaSpring Code,

```
ERROR 26299 --- [           main] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [************] ...............
```

ElasticSearch Version in pom.xml : 6.8.1    with Spring Data Elasticsearch version : 3.2.6

ElasticSearch Version of the Remote Server : 6.2.2

I am using High Level Rest Client.

```
 @Override
 @Bean
 public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
 final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
     .connectedTo(elasticsearch_host + ":" + elasticsearch_port).build();
 return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}
```

Spring Version : 2.2.4

Comment: When I am trying to use Elastic verion 6.2.2 in pom.xml with Spring Data version 3.1.10, I am getting this error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate